# Why send JWT token header

Tags: jwt

Looking at typical JWT tokens I can tell the header mostly identifies the signature scheme being used. For a given web application it may be only a single signature scheme, say HS256. So the header is then merely a base64 representation of:

```
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}
```

static content, sent back and forth between client and server.

Why do we need to send a complete JWT token having three sections *header.payload.signature*? From what I've tested skipping the header and only sending *payload.signature* parts does the job. In most cases, using a third-party JWT library would only require to prepend a stored base64 represention of the header to the token for validation, saving a few dozen bytes on each rountrip.

Are there any security issues arising from trimming the header in user-server communication? I do understand this violates the standard, but browsers don't care anyways.

Answer (score 0):

HMAC-SHA2 - 256bit isn't the only option for "alg".
If it's hashed with a different algorithm, such as SHA-3, you'd need to know in order to validate the token.

Comment: Of course it isn't the only algorithm, but once you settle for a single algorithm for access tokens returned by your application the whole header becomes static. The client doesn't do the hashing, nor the signing, so basically you control what's inside the header. That's my point and justifies the question why not skip sending it.

Comment: I understand what you mean.
So the answer to that is that you shouldn't be serving JWTs.
This is better handled by a federation service such as Active Directory.
Security isn't a realm where you want to roll your own unless you truly have to.